# PDO Connect intermittently slow

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I have the following script to connect to the database:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8mb4", 'root', '',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'"));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I am using xampp and intermittently it will take 3+ seconds to load the above (When it isn't doing the above it loads instantly).

I have verified it is the above by using XDebug, please see screenshots below:
[image: Connect 1]
[image: Connect 2]

In google developer tools the TTFB (Time to First Byte) also matches the time it takes to connect to the database.

Things I have tried:

- Setting the ServerName property in http.conf to ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
- Using host 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the connect script
- In http.conf setting the HostnameLookups to Off
- In http.conf change the Listen port to 8080 (Listen 127.0.0.1:8080) this one just caused it to say localhost refused to connect though
- Disabling IPv6 in regedit
- Changed the host file to have the records 127.0.0.1 localhost and 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1
- Disabling XDebug doesn't make a difference
- I have BitDefender Anti Virus installed and have tried disabling that
- Adding skip-name-resolve to my.ini
- Adding bind-address="127.0.0.1" to my.ini
- Flushing the DNS Cache

And probably other things I am forgetting.

I am using Google Chrome but have the same issues with all browsers.

How can I make the connection to the database consistently fast instead of hanging for 3+ seconds?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: is it just me that uses `new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pass);`? so many options? xD

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have edited my question, is that better?

Comment: Now you have no question at all.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have added a question

Answer (score 0):

This is rather just a suggestion, not a solution.
The speed of connecting to your database may vary and depend on the hardware you are using. I have noticed you running it locally.

I am not sure how fast you want it to be, yet if you want to reduce the connection speed time, you should consider using the singleton pattern for subsequent connections.

Generally it should look like the following snippet:

```
Class Database
{
    protected static $connection = null;

    public static function connect ()
    {
         if (! is_null (self::$connection)) {
               return self::$connection;
         }

         self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8mb4", 'root', '' ", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'"));
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

         return self::$connection;
    }
}

Database::connect ()->query ('some random query'); // this will still take 3 sec
Database::connect ()->query ('some random query'); // this will run faster
```

P.S this won't avoid the speed for the first connection, yet sense the connection is left open for subsequent connections it will be fast enough.
Please also read the pros and cons of singleton pattern before adopting it.